# XMLStreamException when trying to read empty file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

My app uses javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader to parse .xml files. I get a:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
```

when trying to parse an empty string during test (the same occurs when passing an empty file). I tried passing just the prolog e.g.:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"`, but exactly the same occurs.

This is the method being tested:

```
public class XMLReportComparator {

public int compareTwoFiles(InputStream filePathA, InputStream filePathB) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

    XMLStreamReader fileA = factory.createXMLStreamReader(filePathA);
    XMLStreamReader fileB = factory.createXMLStreamReader(filePathB);
    boolean empty = true;

    while (fileA.hasNext() && fileB.hasNext()) {
        int eventA = fileA.next(); // this is where the exception happens
        int eventB = fileB.next();
        if (empty) {
            if (!fileA.isWhiteSpace() || !fileB.isWhiteSpace())
                empty = false;
        }
        if (eventA != eventB)
            return 0;
    }
    if (empty)
        return -1;

    return 1;
}
```

This is the test:

```
@Test
public void testTwoEmptyFiles() throws  IOException, XMLStreamException {
    String empty = ""; // or ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    byte[] arr = empty.getBytes();
    byte[] arr2  = empty.getBytes();
    XMLReportComparator p = new XMLReportComparator();
    InputStream inputA = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
    InputStream inputB = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr2);
    Assert.assertTrue(p.compareTwoFiles(inputA, inputB) == -1);
}
```

Even more confusing is the fact that the code throwing the exception actually executes, meaning that `fileA.hasNext()` has to return true...

The documentation seems a little bit obscure to me, can anyone help?

Comment: XML has 1 root node. If it's missing, there's an error.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. Now if an empty file is a valid state in my application, how could I catch just this specific kind of XMLStreamException? Just searching for a string in the message? It seems kinda coarse...

Comment: I found a workaround, but it doesn't "feel good" any more that searching for a string in the exception message. [This](https://coderwall.com/p/3ddyka/how-to-parse-a-file-xml-without-root-or-a-malformed-xml-in-java) one manually adds a root node in the incorrect xml file: